# Testcafe: Scripts are working fine in Firefox browser but are failing in chrome browser because testcafe is not able to scroll

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, scrollbar, testcafe

Testcafe Scripts are working fine over Firefox browser but failing over chrome browser. The reason which we identified is that 'when application is open on Firefox browser testcafe itself scroll down to that element and perform action on that element. But in chrome testcafe itself does not able to scroll down and throws error " The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree". We even tried to forcefully scroll down till the element but it didn't work.

The following testcafe function we have tried are mentioned below:-

1. ScrollBy
2. ScrollIntoView
3. Scroll
4. Keyevent
5. hover
6. mouse down event

The code Snippet we tried are mentioned below :

```
1. const scrollBy = ClientFunction((x, y) => { window.scrollBy(x, y);
  });  const targetElementPosition = Selector('#id'); await
    scrollBy(0, targetElementPosition);

2.const target = Selector('#id');   await t.scrollIntoView(target);
3. await t.scrollBy(0, #id);
4. await t.scrollIntoView(#id)
5. await t.pressKey('pagedown')
6. await t.hover('#id')
7. const target =Selector('#id');    await t.scrollIntoView(target);
8. var el = Selector(document.getElementById(id)); el.scrollIntoView(true);
9. const target = Selector('#target');
     await t
    .dispatchEvent(target, 'mousedown')
    .wait(5000)
```

please suggest solution for this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Scroll TestCafe works correctly in Chrome. Here is an example that demonstrates this:

```js
fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;
   
test(`New Test`, async t => {
    await t
        .resizeWindow(360, 240)
        .hover('#tried-test-cafe')
        .wait(2000);
});
```

So, the issue is that TestCafe can't find the matching element in the DOM. Please share an example of a page that reproduces the incorrect behavior.

Comment: Thank You for the response. As per our company policy we will not be able to share the page details but we can elaborate the scenarios which we are facing. The scroll bar which we are not able to scroll down is in our application's scroll bar. so kindly share approaches if you have any.

Comment: Implementation details of your page are not needed. An example is enough, containing a minimum amount of details but allowing us to understand exactly what the malfunction is. Do you use any standard components in your application? If so, you can try to reproduce this behavior in demos of these components. In any case, without determining the source of the error, it is impossible to find ways to resolve it.
Also, when compiling an example, you may find this article useful: https://testcafe.io/402636/faq?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue

Comment: We have an attribute in CSS that is  "overflow-y: overlay;"  because of this attribute testcafe is not able to scroll and testcafe is not able to find the element which is not visible on the screen. When we change the attribute to  "overflow-y: auto;" then testcafe is able to scroll to the element. but we can't make these changes in our applications CSS as it is required. so could you please tell us how can we scroll with this CSS attribute ("overflow-y: overlay;") in testcafe?

Answer (score 1):

The `overlay` value is invalid for the `overflow-y` property. Chrome treats it as `auto` and Firefox treats it as an error. The scroll functions don't work because Firefox doesn't consider the element's content to be scrollable. If you think that this is not a problem for your application in Firefox, and for the user everything looks fine (although it probably doesn't and it's better to fix it in the application), then you can try replacing the `overflow-y` style with ClientFunction:

```js
const setStyle = ClientFunction((selector, key, value) => {
  document.querySelector(selector).style[key] = value;
})
```

Comment: could you please provide us with an example, how we can change the value of CSS attribute ("overflow-y: overlay" to "overflow-y: auto;"  ) through our testcafe script (JS file)?

Comment: I made a repository that demonstrates how this function works: [https://github.com/felis2803/testcafe-temp-4](https://github.com/felis2803/testcafe-temp-4). Please execute the commands specified in `readme.md`.

The code of the function you are interested in is in [https://github.com/felis2803/testcafe-temp-4/blob/main/index.js](https://github.com/felis2803/testcafe-temp-4/blob/main/index.js).